# K8s getting error after change gcloud sdk location on Macos

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, gcloud

I'm just fished connect to my kubernete.

But affter that I need to change the gcloud location from `/Download` to `/usr` folder.

Next, I run `install.sh` file for update the new location in `.bash_profile`.

Then I check `gcloud` command. It working well

But when I run `kubectl get pod`. The error showing.

`Unable to connect to the server: error executing access token command "/Users/panda/Downloads/google-cloud-sdk/bin/gcloud config config-helper --format=json": err=fork/exec /Users/panda/Downloads/google-cloud-sdk/bin/gcloud: no such file or directory output= stderr=`

Hmm, how to update the location of `gcloud sdk` for solve this problem.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your Kubeconfig file (probably in `~/.kube/config`) you’ll see it has the old path to your `gcloud` CLI. Update that file with the new path.